# Quadratic sort of ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have been attempting to use a quadratic sort in java, to sort an arraylist of messages.
I have used the following code, however it will not compile for me. The error I keep getting is

> cannot find symbol variable length

Below is the sort and the swap I am using:

```
 public static void quadraticSort(ArrayList<Message> m)


{
    String s1 = "abcd";
    String s2 = "efgh";
    int val = "abcd".compareTo("efgh");

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i += 1)
    {
        for (int s2 = i; s2 < s1.length; s2 += 1)
       {
           if ((int)s1[s2].messageText.compareTo(0) <(int)s2[i].messageText.compareTo(0))

           {
               swap(s1, i, s2);
           }
        }

    } 
}

private static void swap(ArrayList<Message> list, int to, int from)
{
   Message temp = list[to];
   list.set(to , from);
   list.set(from , temp);
}
```

Comment: String instances don't have a `length` field. However, they have a `length()` method.

Comment: You're also trying to use an indexer on a `String`, that won't work.

Comment: Yes. Strings in Java don't behave like arrays, they are objects. Use `"hello".charAt(0)` instead of `"hello"[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you're trying to access a `length` property/field of your `String` instances, which does not exist. Instead, you want to use the `length()` *method:*

```
String s = "abc";
s.length(); // = 3
s.length; // compiler error
```

But you have more bugs than that. You're also attempting to access an indexed value of your String using array/bracket notation:

`s1[s2]`

The characters of String objects are not accessible in this manner. You should use the `charAt()` method instead.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have re-factored my code, however the compiler is telling me that charAt cannot be applied to given types at the int val = section.

Comment: I don't think that's where you want it? You can ask a separate, specific question and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the javadoc for [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). In Java they are treated as first class objects; not an array of characters.

To get the length of a string, you must use `length()`. Additionally, to get a character from a given position in the `String`, you must use `charAt(int index)`